# Time to [grab] your torch and pitchforks

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

There's actually a tag for [grab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grab). It has no excerpt, no wiki, 8 followers, and 124 question tagged with it. It needs to go.

To answer the usual [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, not in the slightest. Someone can't really be an expert in "grab."

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Grabbing?

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Nope, none whatsoever.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Again, no. There are various grab functions in a handful of different languages, and those questions if needed, could be retagged with language-specific tags, however "grab" itself is generic.

Comment: Looks like there are at least a couple of bits of software with this name - one of which is some sort of screen capture tool for Macs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grab_(software)) and one of which is a command-line tool that's part of Tk (referenced in https://stackoverflow.com/q/25965921/1709587; if you're on a Unix system and you have it installed, you can probably read about it by typing `man grab`). The latter concept *is* on-topic here. So the water is slightly muddier than you suggest; it's a thoroughly ambiguous tag, but at least one possible meaning refers to an on-topic concept.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Done. That tag was a living tribute to doing it wrong. Fortunately, it wasn't the *only* tag being used on any posts. If it surfaces again I'll blacklist it.

[image]

[Image credit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121570/50049)

Comment: Trivia: We actually once had a _computer_ tag, too, on thousands of questions. Because you _totally_ need a computer tag on a programming site!

Comment: We should introduce the [tag:programming] tag. For all the questions that are *actually* about programming.

Comment: Was going to pull a joke on the [tag:tag] tag too, but I just realized that's a real thing...